# Better way to sort an array with unusual value

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this array:

```
@raw_stack = (
    '900244~dfasdf~ddd3',
    '900122~dfasdf~ddd1',
    '900244~dfasdf~ddd2',
    '900456~dfasdf~ddd4',
    '900312~dfasdf~ddd3',
    '900456~dfasdf~ddd5',
    );
```

I'd like to sort it by the first '~' element.
Is there a more elegant way to solve this rather than
looping and splitting through each value?

Comment: If every first elements are 6-digits long, you can do a simple `@sorted = sort @raw_stack;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort and list slices?

```
sort { ( split( /~/, $a ) )[0] <=> ( split( /~/, $b ) )[0] } @raw_stack;
```

Comment: I was able to figure out this solution eventually :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
my @raw_stack = (
    '900244~dfasdf~ddd3',
    '900122~dfasdf~ddd1',
    '900244~dfasdf~ddd2',
    '900456~dfasdf~ddd4',
    '900312~dfasdf~ddd3',
    '900456~dfasdf~ddd5',
);
my @sorted = 
    map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { [$_, (split/~/)[0]] } @raw_stack;
dump@sorted;
```

**Benchmark:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);


my $s = '~dfasdf~ddd3';
my @arr = ();
for(0..20000) {
    push @arr, int(rand(100000)) . $s;
}
my $count = -3;
cmpthese($count, {
        'ST' => sub {
            my @sorted = 
                map { $_->[0] }
                sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
                map { [$_, (split/~/)[0]] } @arr;
        },
        'SORT' => sub {
            my @sorted =
                sort {
                    my ($a_0) = split /~/, $a;
                    my ($b_0) = split /~/, $b;
                    $a_0 <=> $b_0
                } @arr;
        },
    });
```

**result:**

**array of 200 elements:**

```
      Rate SORT   ST
SORT 267/s   -- -61%
ST   689/s 158%   --
```

**array of 2000 elements:**

```
       Rate SORT   ST
SORT 18.0/s   -- -71%
ST   61.5/s 242%   --
```

**array of 20000 elements:**

```
       Rate SORT   ST
SORT 1.35/s   -- -73%
ST   4.96/s 266%   --
```

Comment: @ikegami: Right with this small array.

Answer (score 2):

These might help. They show you how to extract parts of strings to use them to sort the larger strings:

- Perlmonks [How do I sort an array by (anything)?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=How%20do%20I%20sort%20an%20array%20by%20(anything)%3F)
- perlfaq4 [How do I sort an array by (anything)?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-sort-an-array-by-(anything)%3f)
- Stackoverflow [Perl - Sort CSV on a certain column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4221424/8817)

Answer (score 1):

Is it always 6 digits? If so, the following would be the simplest and fastest:

```
my @sorted_stack = sort @raw_stack;
```

If not,

```
my @sorted_stack =
   sort {
      my ($a_0) = split /~/, $a;
      my ($b_0) = split /~/, $b;
      $a_0 <=> $b_0
   } @raw_stack;
```

A Schwartzian transform might be cleaner if you're used to that, but it's actually slower in this case: [**Update**: Apparently, it's actually faster than my second solution for larger lists. It's never faster than the first, though ]

```
my @sorted_stack =
   map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
     map [ $_, split /~/ ],
      @raw_stack;
```