# Input a list from a file in Perl

Tags: perl, list, file, text, input

I would like to input data from a list in Perl. So far, I have been pasting lists of data into the actual program for it to process. My original sorting program looked like this:

```
# /perl/bin


use strict; #force perl to code properly
use warnings; #find typing mistakes in program like missing semicolons, etc.

use Text::ParseWords; #parse text into an array of tokens or array of arrays

my @rows;

while (<DATA>) {
    push @rows, [ parse_line(',', 0, $_) ];
}

@rows = sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } @rows;

open OUTPUT, ">OUTPUT.TXT";

foreach (@rows) {
    print OUTPUT join ',', @$_;
}

__DATA__
SMITH,M,1
JONES,F,1
...
```

But I would like to have it input from a file that has this list instead. I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track but this is what I have so far:

```
# /perl/bin


use strict;                     #force perl to code properly
use warnings;                   #find typing mistakes in program like missing semicolons, etc.
use autodie;                    #replace functions with ones that succeed or die with lexical scope

use Text::ParseWords;               #parse text into an array of tokens or array of arrays

open(MYINPUTFILE, "<inputfile.txt");        # open for input

my @rows = <MYINPUTFILE>;               # read file into list

while (<MYINPUTFILE>) {
    push @rows, [ parse_line(',', 0, $_) ];
}

@rows = sort { $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] } @rows;

open OUTPUT, ">OUTPUT.TXT";

foreach (@rows) {
    print OUTPUT join ',', @$_;
}
```

Comment: You're presenting us with a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to do with your code? Sort the lines in a CSV based on the third field?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do. Sorry for the XY problem, I didn't even know that's what I was doing!

Comment: What is the problem ? Any output ?

Comment: See [Sort CSV on a certain column?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4221424)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the crux of your problem:

```
open(MYINPUTFILE, "<inputfile.txt");        # open for input

my @rows = <MYINPUTFILE>;               # read file into list
```

Since "@rows =" gives a "wantarray" or list
context to the right-hand side, 
"<>" reads the entire file.

Then:

```
while (<MYINPUTFILE>) {                 # try to read file again,
                                        # but you've already read it all
    push @rows, [ parse_line(',', 0, $_) ];
}
```

You're trying to read the file twice.

There are other issues with your code, but you probably meant to write only:

```
open(MYINPUTFILE, "<inputfile.txt");        # open for input

my @rows;

while (<MYINPUTFILE>) {
    push @rows, [ parse_line(',', 0, $_) ];
}
```

… by parallel to your earlier version.

At the least, you might consider a couple of Perlish changes;

open my $input_file, '<', 'inputfile.txt';

Using a lexical ("my") variable instead of a *FILEHANDLE is nicer in any more complex situation than this one. (Among other things, you can pass it to a subroutine much more easily.) Using the three-argument form of `open` also protects you against problems if you allow others to specify the filename to your program. You then would use `<$input_file>` in your `while` loop.

Comment: But, it should be `open(...) or die` or `use autodie;`.

Comment: @Axeman the OP uses `autodie` in their "this is what I have so far" script.